# How to know the destination directory before installing a package?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, deb

I want to install a large multi GiB package, (mostly just a load of optional data used by another package.) but I need to know what directories it will use *before* installing so that I can mount another partition at that location.

How do I show this destination directory info? It does not seem to be in the package details I get with `apt info -a` nor is it in a verbose dry run `apt-get install <package> -sV` I tried `dpkg -L <package>` but that only works on installed packages. I have not downloaded the .deb yet.

I am using Debian Bullseye(11) and apt package management, standard binary repositories. I'm leaving off the specific package name because I need an answer that is reusable for other packages. If the answer also works with source packages even better.

Question "How do I find the files installed by a particular package? Where is the .deb file to look at? " is not at all what my question is asking, mine is about package info prior to downloading and the other is obtaining system information post installation.

Comment: The last part of the linked question covers your case: “Can I find the package's file list entirely on-line, without explicitly downloading any .deb files and *before* installing anything with `apt`? How?” The accepted answer mentions `apt-file list`.

Comment: (And where it mentions `apt-file`, it says "If you want to list the contents of a package before installing it")

Answer (score 0):

I found there is another apt tool that will provide the needed info `apt-file list <package>` The package of interest does not need to be downloaded.

The install directories info can be found by digging around the Debian packages website for the package "filelist" but apt-file is a more direct command line method.